# How to bind a repeater on click on a row of another repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater bind by the data coming from database. Now on click of its row i want to bind another repeater of detailed information.**One thing more both are not nested**. 
OK Let me explain with an example, I have a repeater of classes. This repeater has binding information about all classes in school.Now I have another Repeater for detailed information of a particular class.Now when i click on a particular class in list of classes, then i will get the detailed information i.e. bind the second repeater using the class id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..So you know the particular id of row which the user clicks.In the click event get the id and pass it to your stored procedure or what ever way you are binding to the repeater.check this below..

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repGrd" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>      
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" Runat="server" RowID='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' OnCommand="clickbutton">Click Here</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the code behind goes like this..

```
 #region On click of row binding repeater
    public void clickbutton(Object sender,CommandEventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
            //Getting the ID of clicked row
            string RowIDval=((LinkButton)sender).Attributes["RowID"].ToString().Trim();

        // Write your code here to bind the repeater as you got the ID
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    }
    #endregion
```

Try this out.

Comment: If you use the CommandArgument attribute of the LinkButton it would  be easier to retrieve the id

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

A UserControl that displays extended information about a Class. A web form with a repeater that binds on a collection of Class entities. The ItemTemplate of the repeater consists of a header for general class info and an instance of the UserControl we created with `Visibility`  set to false. We then turn this UC on/off depending on whether the user wants to see details.

Some code:

**Entities**

```
public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClassDetails : Class
{
    public int NumberOfWeeks
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

**The `ClassDetails` User Control**

(aspx)

```
<hr />
Class Details:<br />
Number of Weeks: <asp:Label ID="lblNumWeeks" runat="server" />
<hr />
```

(code-behind)

```
public void Populate(ClassDetails classDetails)
{
    this.lblNumWeeks.Text = classDetails.NumberOfWeeks.ToString();
}
```

**The WebForm**

(aspx)

```
<%@ Register Src="~/ClassDetailsUC.ascx" TagPrefix="SO" TagName="ClassDetailsUC" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptClassList" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblClassName" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" Visible="false" runat="server">
                    <br />
                    <SO:ClassDetailsUC ID="ucClassDetails" runat="server" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

(.cs file)

```
/// <summary>
/// Page-level collection of Class instances
/// </summary>
List<ClassDetails> classes;

/// <summary>
/// The current class id we are displaying extended information for
/// </summary>
private int? ActiveId
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ViewState["ClassIdDetails"] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return (int?)this.ViewState["ClassIdDetails"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["ClassIdDetails"] = value;
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.rptClassList.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptClassList_ItemDataBound);
    this.rptClassList.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(rptClassList_ItemCommand);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

void rptClassList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //for now we know this is the only button on the repeater. so no need to check CommandType
    //set new ActiveId
    this.ActiveId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    //re-bind repeater to refresh data
    this.BindData();
}


/// <summary>
/// For each Class entity bound, we display some basic info. 
/// <para>We also check to see if the current Class is the ActiveId. If it is, turn on the detail panel and populate the ClassDetailsUC</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void rptClassList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Class classItem = (Class)e.Item.DataItem;
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblClassName")).Text = classItem.Name;
        ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnShow")).CommandArgument = classItem.Id.ToString();
        if (this.ActiveId.HasValue && this.ActiveId == classItem.Id)
        {
            //we want to display details for this class
            ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlDetails")).Visible = true;
            //get ClassDetails instance
            ClassDetails details = this.RetrieveDetails(classItem.Id);
            //populate uc
            ((ClassDetailsUC)e.Item.FindControl("ucClassDetails")).Populate(details);

        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //quick data retrieval process :)
    classes = new List<ClassDetails> { 
        new ClassDetails() { Id = 1, Name = "Class 1" }, 
        new ClassDetails() { Id = 2, Name = "Class 2" }, 
        new ClassDetails() { Id = 3, Name = "Class 3" } 
    };

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        //only bind on initial load
        this.BindData();
    }
}

private void BindData()
{
    this.rptClassList.DataSource = this.classes;
    this.rptClassList.DataBind();
}

/// <summary>
/// Quick function to simulate retrieving a single ClassDetails instance
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private ClassDetails RetrieveDetails(int id)
{
    return this.classes.Where(c => c.Id == id).Single();
}
```